# Prove that if $n+1$ divides $\binom{2^{n}}{2}$ then $n+1$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

It is a straightforward simple question. Is the following statement true:

> If $$n+1\text{ }\Bigg|\text{ } \binom{2^{n}}{2}$$ then $n+1$ is prime.

To see this I write $$\mathfrak a(n) =\binom{2^{n}}{2}$$ then observe that $$5|\mathfrak a(4), 7|\mathfrak a(6),\ldots,19|\mathfrak a(18),\ldots$$

There is no motivation here just curiosity. A counter example would suffice. I would like to think Euler's theorem comes into play but I am not sure how I would apply it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$3+1$ divides $\binom{2^3}{2}=28$ but $3+1$ is not prime.

For more counterexamples, here is a Sage script:

```
for n in range(1,1000):
    if(binomial(2^n,2) % (n+1) == 0 and not is_prime(n+1)):
        print n
```

which prints

```
3
7
15
27
31
63
111
127
255
340
447
495
511
560
644
```

Comment: ? If $n=6$ then $n+1=7$ and $7$ divides $\binom{2^6}{2}$?

Comment: That sequence is not in Sloan's database.

Comment: I suppose that means you have an opportunity to add it.

Comment: I got this hunch playing around in GAP. Anyways the Mersenne prime are in that sequence? Also are you saying that if $n$ is not in that sequence then the claim is true?

Comment: If $n$ is in the range of the `for` loop but isn't printed, then that means $n+1$ doesn't divide $\binom{2^n}{2}$, ***or*** $n+1$ is not prime, ***or*** both.

Comment: If $n=2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime then $n+1=2^p$, which definitely divides
$$\binom{2^n}{2}=\binom{2^{2^p-1}}{2}= \frac{(2^{2^p-1})(2^{2^p-1}-1)}{2} = (2^{2^p-2})(2^{2^p-1}-1)$$
since $p\leq 2^p-2$ for all primes $p$, but $n+1=2^p$ is not itself prime. Therefore any Mersenne prime will be among the counterexamples for your claim.

Answer (score 3):

For $n$ even, then $n+1\mid 2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ implies $n+1\mid 2^n-1$. There exists non-primes $q$ so that $q\mid 2^{q-1}-1$.

For example, $2^{340}-1$ is divisible by $341=11\cdot 31$, so $n=340$ is a counterexample with $n$ even.

$341$ is the smallest [Euler pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_pseudoprime) to base $2$. Any Euler psuedoprime $q$ to base $2$ yields $n=q-1$ as a counterexample. There might be other cases - the property that $2^{q-1}-1$ is divisible by $q$ covers potentially some numbers that are not pseudo.

According to Wikipedia, the first Euler pseudoprimes to base $2$ are:

> $341, 561, 1105, 1729, 1905, 2047, 2465, 3277, 4033, 4681, 5461, 6601, 8321, 8481$